# cursor size emacs installed through guix

Tags: emacs, guix

I have an Arch-linux system and I just installed guix. Using Guix, I installed emacs. When I use the pacman-installed emacs all is well but when I use the guix-installed emacs, the mouse cursor gets really small every time the mouse hover over the emacs window.

I have an hidpi screen which should be the cause but I don't know why the mouse does not recognize the dpi of the system when using guix-installed emacs.

- emacs version is 28.1 (same as the system-wide version of emacs)
- I use i3 wm

EDIT: I did the test and the problem does not happen when I use sway (Wayland wm) instead of i3. I guess this is a problem between Xorg and guix.

Comment: I have the same issue on Debian and Guix. Unfortunately, I don't know an answer, yet, so I can only upvote and give my +1(;

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Debian and I have the same issue as you. I've tried the regular ways to increase cursor size like setting `Xcursor.size` in `~/.Xresources`, but to no avail. Then, I realized that Guix set a `XCURSOR_PATH`. My fix was to set `XCURSOR_PATH` manuall in `.xinitrc` to both the path from Debian and Guix:

```
export XCURSOR_PATH=/usr/share/icons/:/home/munen/.guix-profile/share/icons
```